# pausing function on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a function written in javascript that allows me to scroll through an array of images iterated at a certain interval, now I would like to add some more functionality to it by pausing the rotation when I hover over any of the images in the array.

**Javascript**

```
(function() {
    var rotator = document.getElementById('bigImage');
    var imageDir = '../images/headers/';
    var delayInSeconds = 5;
    var images = ['ImageOne.png', 'ImageTwo.png', 'ImageThree.png', 'ImageFour.png',
        'ImageFive.png',
        'ImageSix.png'];
    var num = 0;
    var changeImage = function() {
        var len = images.length;
        bigImage.src = imageDir + images[num++];
        if (num == len) {
            num = 0;
        }
    };
    setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);

})();​
```

Comment: Which is it `rotator` or `bigImage`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery:

```
var rotationRunning = true;

var changeImage = function() {
    if (rotationRunning) {
        var len = images.length;
        rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
        if (num == len)
            num = 0;
        }
    }
};

$(rotator).hover(
    function() { rotationRunning = false; },
    function() { rotationRunning = true; }
);
```

Comment: See Alexander's question. I assumed that bigImage variable is the same as rotator variable.

Answer (score 4):

You could store the id returned from setInterval, and pass it to clearInterval when the image is hovered over.

So, on mouse over, you clear, and on mouse out you set it going again.

Hope that helps!